# boolean values from php integer

Tags: php

I am querying a database and it is returning a long integer of boolean values.  E.g     0011000000000100001000000010000000000100000000000000.

Each of the 1 values equate to a string.  E.g. Air Conditioning or Power Steering.  If the value is 0 then the Vehicle doesn't have this option.

I am trying to work out a way to loop through this large integer and return the name of each "Option" that the car has.

I'm very new to PHP and would very much appreciate the help if anyone has a solution.

Many thanks
Andrew

Comment: Is it an integer or boolean? They are two different cast types

Answer (score 3):

That is most likely a string, and you can just iterate through it and for every one, look up the name in a map:

```
$option_map = array(
  'Air Conditioning',
  'Sun roof',
  'Power Steering',
  'Brakes',
  //.. Fill with all options
  // Could populate from a database or config file
);

$str = '0011000000000100001000000010000000000100000000000000';
$strlen = strlen($str);
for($i = 0; $i < $strlen; $i++){
  if($str[$i] === '1'){
    $options[] = $option_map[$i];
  }
}

// $options is an array containing each option
```

[Demo Here](http://ideone.com/4vfxkT). There are empty options in the array, because the options map is not complete. It correctly fills in the "Power Steering" and "Brakes", corresponding to the first two `1`'s in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like this.

1. Loop through the length of the string
2. Assign each option in an array (then you can later access any item in the array, or pass the entire array to another function which can pull your values.
3. Create a function such as `get_car_option` and pass the position as well as the value

```php
//force the value to be a string, where $longint is from your DB
$string = (string) $longint;

for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++)
{
    $array[$i] = get_car_option($i, substr($string, $i, 1));
}

//example of function
function get_car_option($pos, $value)
{
    //you can then use this function to get the
    //...values based on each number position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Something like:

```
$myVal = 170; //10101010 in binary

$flags = array(
  'bumpers' => 1,     //00000001
  'wheels' => 2,      //00000010
  'windshield' => 4,  //00000100
  'brakes' => 8,      //00001000
  ...
);

echo "The car has: ";

foreach( $flags as $key => $value ) {
  if( $myVal & $value ) {
    echo $key . " and ";
  }
}

// Output: Car has: wheels and brakes and
```

You could also use the shift right `>>` operator and go by powers of two, but I'm not bored enough to write that code.